# DataGrid refresh not working when I use method from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a method to refresh my `DataGrid` after add/edit/delete data.

```
public void EmployeesDbConnection<T>(T dbset, string collectionName, Page page) where T : class
{
    CompanyManagerContext db = new CompanyManagerContext();

    var collectionViewSource = page.FindResource(collectionName) as CollectionViewSource;

    db.Set<T>().Load();
    collectionViewSource.Source = db.Set<T>().Local;
    collectionViewSource.View.Refresh();
}
```

My problem is that my method is working only when I use it in the same window/page, where my datagrid is.

A scenario is:

I have `DataGrid` in EmployeePage.
I have **Add** `Button` in EmployeePage.

When I click **Add** `Button`, on display it shows a new `Window` (AddEmployeeWindow) with  fields to enter the employee data e.g (name, lastname, birthdate etc) and add, reset and cancel buttons.

When I click the **Add** `Button`, my data inserts to database but `DataGrid` won't refresh.

When I am doing the same thing in employee page it refreshes.

In EmployeePage I run a method like this(`DataGrid` is refreshing):

```
dbManagement.EmployeesDbConnection(newEmployee, "CollectionViewSource", this);
```

In AddWindow I run method like this(`DataGrid` is not refreshing):

```
dbManagement.EmployeesDbConnection(newEmployee, "CollectionViewSource",     empPage);
```

with

```
readonly EmployeePages empPage = new EmployeePages();
```

Its XAML code of bindings:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type models:Employee}, CreateList=True}"></CollectionViewSource>
</Page.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="EmployeesDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,355,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="305" Width="880"
                  DataContext="{StaticResource CollectionViewSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IdColumn" Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FirstNameColumn" Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LastNameColumn" Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MobilePhoneNumberColumn" Header="Mobile Phone" Binding="{Binding MobilePhoneNumber}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="EmailAdressColumn" Header="Email" Binding="{Binding MailAdress}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="EmployeedDate" Header="Employeed Date" Binding="{Binding EmployedDate}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BirthdayDate" Header="Birthday     Date" Binding="{Binding BirthDate}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: If you have implemented WPF bindings properly, then there is no need to refresh. Grid would update because of two-way binding.

Comment: @Prajwal
i edited my post and add informations about bindings. whats wrong with them?

Comment: you are not binding. `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` you are referring view directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddEmployeeWindow` needs a reference to the *existing* `EmployeePages`. It shouldn't create a *new* instance of this page.

You could inject the window with a reference to the `EmployeePages` when you open it:

```
AddEmployeeWindow win = new AddEmployeeWindow(this); //<--
win.Show();
```

Don't forget to modify the constructor of the `AddEmployeeWindow` to accept an `EmployeePages` reference:

```
public partial class AddEmployeeWindow : Window
{
    private readonly EmployeePages _empPage;
    public AddEmployeeWindow(EmployeePages empPage)
    {
        _empPage = empPage;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //...
    public void Refresh()
    {
        dbManagement.EmployeesDbConnection(newEmployee, "CollectionViewSource", _empPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thats right. i figured it out when i was comming back to home, that i'm creating a new instance and i need only reference to the old one. anyway thanks for the code i'll implement this tommorow and let u know